# Display nested results from http request after submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

there is a textbox on my page where users type in what a username they want to search and after  click on a submit button. what i want to achieve is when the user hits the submit button the results should be push immediately unto the page. 
With my script what it does is displaying only one result, even though there could be 10 or more

JS

```
.controller('search_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$ionicLoading','$ionicPopup','$state','$stateParams','$cordovaToast',function($scope,$http,$location,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$state,$stateParams,$cordovaToast){
    $scope.username=localStorage.getItem("username");
    $scope.searchresults = [];


        $scope.expendsearch=function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Please Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://localhost/app/templates/spree/sales/expenses/search_results.php",
        {'username':$scope.username})
        .success(function(data){
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.results=data;
        {$ionicLoading.hide();}

        var search ={"fullname":data[0].reciever, "username":data[0].amount};
        $scope.searchresults.push(search);
        }).error(function(error){
        console.error(error);
        });
        }


}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="search_ctrl" ng-repeat="item in searchresults track by $index">
{{item.username}}
{{item.fullname}}
</div>
```

When i change my script to this:

```
  .controller('search_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$ionicLoading','$ionicPopup','$state','$stateParams','$cordovaToast',function($scope,$http,$location,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$state,$stateParams,$cordovaToast){
        $scope.username=localStorage.getItem("username");
        $scope.searchresults = [];


            $scope.expendsearch=function() {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Please Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
            event.preventDefault();
            $http.post("http://localhost/app/templates/spree/sales/expenses/search_results.php",
            {'username':$scope.username})
            .success(function(data){
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.results=data;
            {$ionicLoading.hide();}

            var search ={"fullname":data.reciever, "username":data.amount};
            $scope.searchresults.push(search);
            }).error(function(error){
            console.error(error);
            });
            }


    }])
```

Nothing appears on the page

Comment: what you are getting in `data` ?

Comment: i get nested results of reciever and amount. more than one result

Comment: I got to know that. But could you somewhere paste it and show what exactly you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

If the first script displays one result, i assume your data comes in the format

```
[{reciever:'aaa',amount:'bbb'},{reciever:'ccc',amount:'ddd'} ....]
```

so you can do `$scope.searchResults = data;`

and in the html, do

```
<div ng-controller="search_ctrl" ng-repeat="item in searchresults track by $index">
{{item.reciever}}
{{item.amount}}
</div>
```

Comment: there is more than one data

Comment: you really need to show me the structure of data before i can answer that